# Selection .val has strange, in-understandable value (Chosen plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In Ruby-on-Rails, I am using the Chosen plugin on a multiselector for a list of provinces as below:

```
<%= select_tag :provinces,
options_for_select(DataHelper::all_provinces_captions.zip(DataHelper::all_provinces_ids)),
{:multiple => true, class: 'chosen-select chzn-select',
:data => {:placeholder => 'Filter Provinces/States'}}%>
```

I also have a selector in a form field on the same page like so:

```
<%= f.select :province_ids,
  (DataHelper::all_provinces_captions.zip(DataHelper::all_provinces_ids)),
                 { include_blank: true }, {
                 multiple: true, data: {placeholder: 'Filter Provinces/States'} }
%>
```

Finally, I have a Javascript function that synchronizes the two when #provinces, with class .chzn-select changes:

```
var selectedVals = [];

$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {
  $("#provinces option:selected").each(function () {
    console.log ("this value is " + ($(this).val));
    selectedVals.push($(this).val);
  });
  $("#education_plan_province_ids").empty(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
    console.log (selectedVals[i] + " selected");
    $("#education_plan_province_ids").append($("<option>" + selectedVals[i] + "</option>")).prop("selected", true);
  }
});
```

However, in my console, instead of getting an output, "this value is alabama" for example, I get the following:

```
this value is function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return
d=n.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d
a.call(this,c,n(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e
e+="":n.isArray(e)&&(e=n.map(e,function(a){return
null==a?"":a+""})),b=n.valHooks[this.type]||n.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase(
],b&&"set"in b&&void 0!==b.set(this,e,"value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return
b=n.valHooks[e.type]||n.valHooks[e.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"get"in b&&void 0!=
(c=b.get(e,"value"))?c:(c=e.value,"string"==typeof c
c.replace(bc,""):null==c?"":c)}}
```

So not surprisingly, I am very confused as to why this is happening!
For a final piece of info, here is all_provinces_captions, all_provinces_ids, canada_provinces_with_caption, and usa_provinces_with_caption in the DataHelper, all arrays:

```
def self.usa_provinces_with_caption
    [["Alabama", "alabama"], ["Alaska", "alaska"], ["Arizona", "arizona"], ["Arkansas", "arkansas"], ["California", "california"], ["Colorado", "colorado"], ["Connecticut", "connecticut"], ["Delaware", "delaware"], ["District Of Columbia", "district of columbia"], ["Florida", "florida"], ["Georgia", "georgia"], ["Hawaii", "hawaii"], ["Idaho", "idaho"], ["Illinois", "illinois"], ["Indiana", "indiana"], ["Iowa", "iowa"], ["Kansas", "kansas"], ["Kentucky", "kentucky"], ["Louisiana", "louisiana"], ["Maine", "maine"], ["Maryland", "maryland"], ["Massachusetts", "massachusetts"], ["Michigan", "michigan"], ["Minnesota", "minnesota"], ["Mississippi", "mississippi"], ["Missouri", "missouri"], ["Montana", "montana"], ["Nebraska", "nebraska"], ["Nevada", "nevada"], ["New Hampshire", "new hampshire"], ["New Jersey", "new jersey"], ["New Mexico", "new mexico"], ["New York", "new york"], ["North Carolina", "north carolina"], ["North Dakota", "north dakota"], ["Ohio", "ohio"], ["Oklahoma", "oklahoma"], ["Oregon", "oregon"], ["Pennsylvania", "pennsylvania"], ["Rhode Island", "rhode island"], ["South Carolina", "south carolina"], ["South Dakota", "south dakota"], ["Tennessee", "tennessee"], ["Texas", "texas"], ["Utah", "utah"], ["Vermont", "vermont"], ["Virginia", "virginia"], ["Washington", "washington"], ["West Virginia", "west virginia"], ["Wisconsin", "wisconsin"], ["Wyoming", "wyoming"]]
end
def self.canada_provinces_with_caption
    [["Alberta", "alberta"], ["British Columbia", "british columbia"], ["Manitoba", "manitoba"], ["New Brunswick", "new brunswick"], ["Newfoundland", "newfoundland"], ["Northwest Territories", "northwest territories"], ["Nova Scotia", "nova scotia"], ["Nunavut", "nunavut"], ["Ontario", "ontario"], ["Prince Edward Island", "prince edward island"], ["Quebec", "quebec"], ["Saskatchewan", "saskatchewan"], ["Yukon", "yukon"]]
end
def self.all_provinces_captions
    usa_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| x.first } + canada_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| x.first }
end
def self.all_provinces_ids
    usa_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| (Province.find_by name: x.first).id} + canada_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| (Province.find_by name: x.first).id }
end
```

Comment: It looks like your missing the () on the end of $(this).val.  It should be $(this).val().

Comment: This is correct! Can you put it as an answer so I can confirm it?

Comment: Will do, glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your missing the parenthesis for the .val method.  Try the following:

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, on your rendered page, inspect the chosen element and check the  element (it usually is hidden) and pick the id there to replace

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {
}
```

for

```
$("#your-id").change(function() {
  // do some stuff
  $("#your-id").trigger("liszt:updated"); //This is necessary when you change your chosen select options, so it refresh the component
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Craig Stroman already has the right answer I think - have not tried yours yet, but thank-you for your help!